# Where did Java get its name from?

Tags: java

Where did Java get it's name from? Is it referring to all the coffee programmers have to drink in order to meet deadlines and maintain some degree of sanity?

Comment: It got it's name just like you; from it's mommy and daddy!

Comment: [So why did they decide to call it Java?](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077265/core-java/so-why-did-they-decide-to-call-it-java-.html), [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(programming_language))

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Java doesn't support multiple inheritance...

Comment: Google "java language name origin"

Comment: @PM77-1 Even Googling just "java name" is good enough.

Comment: Originally it was Oak. Also, every Java class file starts with the magic number 0xCAFEBABE in hex.

Comment: @MadProgrammer - Java supports multiple inheritance of **type** and **behavior**. The only missing component is **state**.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch is that so 0_o

Comment: @James_Parsons [Yes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file).

Comment: @MadProgrammer, inheritance, especially in multiplicity, is overrated! I'd say it's an aggregation. Java *has-a* `Mother` and `Father` which "he" calls `myMother.getName(myFather);`...Lil'Java *is not*-a `Parent` whatever.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils It was a joke ;) Besides, multiple inheritance is only overrated until you need to fully replicated or proxy a whole class in order to work around it.  In 15+ years of using Java, I've only had one occasion where it really annoyed me ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer: I know - me try joke 2!. I hate proxies; didn't Java 8 fix that ;? I feel ya! <36 mo.s and luckily I haven't let it bother me once!

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Not if you need functionality from two concrete classes.  I did really like C++ for this reason, but I like Java's interfaces better. Pros and cons to it all

Comment: @MadProgrammer, ah the paradoxical life we live... Reality sucks - C# rules! :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about computer history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original name of Oak was already a trademark by Oak Systems, so the lawyers said they couldn't use it.  They got together in a meeting to come up with a new name.  See this link, [So why did they decide to call it Java?](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077265/core-java/so-why-did-they-decide-to-call-it-java-.html)  They all give their accounts in this link.

The manager: Kim Polese who organized the meeting is the only person who claims publicly to have come up with the name.  The others couldn't remember for sure.

Answer (score 2):

They couldn't use the original name (Oak?), and the product manager got everyone together to brainstorm new names.

Someone suggested Java.

Answer (score 0):

> The language was initially called Oak after an oak tree that stood
>   outside Gosling's office. Later the project went by the name Green and
>   was finally renamed Java, from Java coffee.

[Source: Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(programming_language)#History)

**Edit:** Sorry, didn't read your post correctly. [Check this.](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077265/core-java/so-why-did-they-decide-to-call-it-java-.html)

**Edit 2:** Oops, sorry, MadProgrammer.